# SQL error : duplicate entry for value'0' PRIMARY

Tags: mysql, sql

I got query:

```
    INSERT INTO peekquick.file_storage 
            (file_id, 
             size, 
             content, 
             file_desc, 
             files_set_id, 
             content_type, 
             file_name, 
             answer_id) 
VALUES      (file_id = 62745251829, 
             size = 1295585, 
             content = '', 
             file_desc = '', 
             files_set_id = '', 
             content_type = 'image/jpeg', 
             file_name = 'witryna.jpeg', 
             answer_id = 176458);
```

and I got error:

```
Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

and I got no clue why this %$#@$^ doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Which column is your `primary key`?

Comment: Check whether identity incremnt is set to true or not at primary column.

Comment: It might be because you need to specify the primary key as auto-increment

Comment: Are you inserting values in FILE_ID manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Make sure the column set as your PRIMARY KEY is set to AUTO_INCREMENT

**`INT`** has a [maximum signed value of 2147483647](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html). Any number greater than that will be truncated to that value.

In Sql Server define the column like this...

```
   FILE_ID [PrimaryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

Then you can add a constraint making it the primary key.

or alter table like this

```
   ALTER TABLE MyTable
   ADD MytableID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (MyTableID)
```

or

[image]

Now go *Column properties* below of it scroll down and find *Identity Specification*, expand it and you will find Is *Identity* make it *Yes*. Now choose *Identity Increment* right below of it give the value you want to increment in it.

[image]
See [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187742.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the FILE_ID=... after VALUES. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO peekquick.FILE_STORAGE (FILE_ID, SIZE, CONTENT, FILE_DESC, FILES_SET_ID, CONTENT_TYPE, FILE_NAME, ANSWER_ID)
  VALUES (62745251829, 1295585, '', '', '', 'image/jpeg', 'witryna.jpeg', 176458);
```

Make sure you primary key is inserted correctly, make it Auto Increment if you are not generating it manually. Also there might be a UNIQUE column in this table, make sure the value you are inserting in this column is unique.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is somewhat unorthodox, does it help to do it like?

```
INSERT INTO peekquick.FILE_STORAGE 
    (FILE_ID, SIZE, CONTENT, FILE_DESC, FILES_SET_ID, CONTENT_TYPE, FILE_NAME, ANSWER_ID)
VALUES 
    (62745251829, 1295585, '', '', '', 'image/jpeg', 'witryna.jpeg', 176458);
```